# Nuget package not adding reference on custom package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I created a nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyPackage.dll</id>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <owners>Me</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>The description</description>
    <tags>tag1</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

In a directory with the file strucutre

> - MyPackage
>
>   - Assemblies
>
>     - MyPackage.dll
>   - MyPackage.nuspec

I created my package using `nuget.exe pack myPackage.nuspec` and placed it in my local sources. I can find and install it from visual studio at which point

- The dll is copied into the packages directory
- But the reference is not added to the project
- No repositories.config is created
- No packages.config is created

What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In case someone runs into this in the future. The solution was that the 'Assemblies' directory needed to be renamed 'lib'. The documentation was wrong (been updated, now it's correct).

[Big thanks to dotnetjunky over on codeplex](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/258394)